# How does Sanctuary interact with "reflected" damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Through a peculiar course of events with a touch of homebrew, my cleric got to learn the spell [Armor of Agathys](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/armor-of-agathys) (Player's Handbook p. 215) which has the effect:

> If a creature hits you with a melee attack ... the creature takes 5 cold damage.

As a regular user of the [Sanctuary](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) spell, I wondered how these spells would interact in the following situation:

1. Casting Sanctuary on myself as soon as fight starts
2. Casting Armor of Agathys to add an additional defense
3. A goblin succeeds the Sanctuary saving throw and hits me with a melee attack
4. The goblin takes damage due to Armor of Agathys.

Does the Sanctuary spell end because I casted Armor of Agathys and after Sanctuary and the spell affects the goblin when it takes damages ?

Would Sanctuary end if I were to cast Armor of Agathys 10 mins ago because this dark and shadowy dungeon looked dangerous ?

Would Sanctuary break if the damage reflection came from the effect of a racial trait or a kinda spiky enchanted armour ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Sanctuary breaks in all those cases

The Errata (v. 2.0, 2018) has changed the last sentence of *sanctuary* to :

> If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an
> enemy, or **deals damage to another creature**, this spell ends. (emphasis mine)

Thus it does not matter when you cast *armor of Agathys*. If it triggers and deals damage to a creature, it will violate the terms of *sanctuary* and cause it to end. The same would be true for other sources of damage too that originate from you (including from your equipment).

Comment: Thanks. I will never again use roll20 for reference.